# JAVA - how can I create an array of BST nodes that lie in a given range

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to write code in

> java

for creating an array for a given range in BST.

I found only code for [Count BST nodes that lie in a given range](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-bst-nodes-that-are-in-a-given-range/)

I thought maybe to find first the length of the wanted array, and then to create it and then "go through" the tree again and add the wanted values to the array in recursive function , but Im not sure if this is the best way and also Im not sure how to do so (Im new in java..)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of the code (from the link you gave) that returns the data of the nodes within range as a list:

```
  List<Integer> getWithinRange(Node node, int low, int high) 
  { 
    ArrayList<Integer> withinRange = new ArrayList<>();

    // Base Case 
    if(node == null) 
        return withinRange; 

    // If current node is in range, then  
    // include it in count and recur for  
    // left and right children of it 
    if(node.data >= low && node.data <= high) {
      withinRange.add(node.data);
      withinRange.addAll(this.getWithinRange(node.left, low, high)); 
      withinRange.addAll(this.getWithinRange(node.right, low, high));
    }

    // If current node is smaller than low,  
    // then recur for right child 
    else if(node.data < low) 
      withinRange.addAll(this.getWithinRange(node.right, low, high));

    // Else recur for left child 
    else
      withinRange.addAll(this.getWithinRange(node.left, low, high));

    return withinRange;
  }
```